# Error Using PostGIS Address Standardizer

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to use the PostgreSQL 9.5 and PostGIS address standardizer to parse an address field. The particular field in the table I am working with only has the street name and the street type (ex. 'MAIN ST'). Ultimately what I would like to do is create an insert statement from the existing table into a new, empty table, but for now I will just settle for getting this to work.

I have created the 'address_standardizer_data_us' extension. But when I try to use the information directly from the Postgre documentation:

```
SELECT house_num, name, suftype, city, country, state, unit  FROM standardize_address('us_lex',
           'us_gaz', 'us_rules', 'One Devonshire Place, PH 301, Boston, MA 02109');
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function standardize_address(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: ..., name, suftype, city, country, state, unit  FROM standardiz...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function standardize_address(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 67
```

What am I missing here? Can I substitute the string 'One Devonshire Place, PH 301, Boston, MA 02109' with a field name in an insert statment?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your statement, the same statement works on my install.  Did you run 'CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer_data_us;' ?  Sounds like your install didn't go right but I can't help with an install issue.

Comment: @kttii, yes I did create the extension

Comment: Make sure the extension is showing:  `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name LIKE '%address%';`  ... mine says version 2.2.2.  The only other thing I can think of is a permission issue.

Comment: Mine is 2.2.1, do you think that makes a difference?

Answer (score 2):

I did:

```
create extension address_standardizer;
```

to make it work with the same error.

I have postgis 2.2.2, postgres 9.3 and ubuntu 14.04